# PHP: How to increase a number in variable that contains both text and the number

Tags: php, variable-variables

This is quite a stupid question. I want to find out how to increase a number in the end of the variable:

```
$Coffee1 = "black";
$Coffee2 = "brown";
$Coffee3 = "gray";

echo $Coffee1;        => black
echo $Coffee1+1;      => brown
echo $Coffee2+1;      => gray
```

Comment: PHP has [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but IMO this is a terrible language feature. Why do you have these variables? Would a single [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) be a better fit?

Comment: No questions are stupid if you intend to learn from the answer.

Comment: Chris: There is a mysql database I need to read. In the database tables are named like Coffee1, Coffee2, Coffee3. All the tables include 10 rows with same row names. I've been trying to make a single "while", which would read all the tables instead of multiple "hiles". I'm not familiar enough with php to solve the problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism you're looking for is an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
$coffee = [
    "black",
    "brown",
    "gray"
];

$index = 0;

echo $coffee[$index]; // "black"
echo $coffee[$index+1]; // "brown"
echo $coffee[$index+2]; // "gray"
```

This is also where loops become handy.

```
foreach($coffee as $flavor) {
    echo $flavor;
}
// "blackbrowngrey"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that ([code](https://ideone.com/Z3KowA)):

```
<?php

$Coffee1 = "black";
$Coffee2 = "brown";
$Coffee3 = "gray";

$varName = "Coffee";
for($varIdx = 1; $varIdx <= 3; $varIdx++) {
    echo "\n";
    echo ${$varName . $varIdx};
}
```

Here is some explanation : Variable variables [1](http://www.dummies.com/programming/php/how-to-use-php-variable-variables/), [2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

But better use arrays instead of variables in this case.